# Rewrite and Redirect urls to change the folder name from the urls

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Problem:

```
https://mydomain/folder1/xyz/product1
```

to

```
https://mydomain/xyz/product1
```

Remember folder1 is non-existent. I just want to rewrite it externally and internally it should point to old link. For example

if user clicks:     https://mydomain/folder1/xyz/product1  the user automatically showed a link     https://mydomain/xyz/product1
in browser but the content should still come from     https://mydomain/folder1/xyz/product1

Solutions tried 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(folder)\ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]
```

.htaccess file

```html
RewriteOptions inherit

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^best-price/(.+)$ /$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>



# Header unset Pragma
# FileETag None
# Header unset ETag
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
# Disable server signature
ServerSignature Off
```

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite /folder1/xyz to /xyz try the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^folder1/(.+)$ /$1 [L]
```

htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: why this php in 5th and 6 th line

Comment: @AnkitJain sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]` i didn't get the meaning of this line. Why you are using `.php` in it. My Urls does not contain `php`

Comment: @Ankitjain this is to rewrite **file** to **/file.php** The RewriteCond checks if **Documentroot/$1.php is file** then rewrite it. The RewriteCond is invalid without **.php**

Comment: sorry if i misunderstood something, It just improved your orignal rule.

Comment: I Checked but its not working. I added `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^best-price/(.+)$ /$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>` in htaccess. And tried opening this url (https://www.pricereview.in/best-price/mobile-price-in-india/cellkon/celkon-c344/)

Comment: @Ankitjain what url are you going to?

Comment: Here is what i am currently doing. when i added your updated code and tried hitting (https://www.pricereview.in/best-price/mobile-price-in-india/cellkon/celkon-c344/) it will not change the url to (https://www.pricereview.in/mobile-price-in-india/cellkon/celkon-c344/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110947/discussion-between-ankit-jain-and-starkeen).

Comment: @ankitJain Does the destination url 

 https://mydomain/xyz/product1 work if you directly enter it in your browser?

Comment: i want the browser to show  (www.mydomain/xyz/product1) not this  (www.mydomain/folder1/xyz/product1)

Comment: Updated the file please check @starkeen

Comment: tried clearing the cache.. if you can help wp rewrite

Comment: @Ankitjain try the updated code, i have added a R flag to the rule

Comment: Are you still getting the same result?